# How to access angular routing data outside angular app

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to generate sitemap for each module on build time.

My Project structure

```
- cli
- client
   -- Module A
      -- Routing A
   -- Module B
      -- Routing B
   -- Module C
      -- Routing C
- server
```

I need to access the router data of each modules in the `CLI` folder to generate the sitemap for respective modules.

I have the logic to generate the sitemap. But I dono how to access the router data.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To get the active route without subscribing to router events, you can simply use a while loop recursively to find the lowest child.

```
private getActivatedRoute(): ActivatedRoute {
    let route = this.router.routerState.root;
    while (route.firstChild) {
        route = route.firstChild;
    }
    return route;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `Cli` is not an angular app

Answer (score 0):

Not very good solution, but you can put your data in to `window` object, and then get it from other module:

```
const routeData = {name: 'home'}
window['routeData'] = {...routeData};
```